# Calculating the number of days between dates including magnitude in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, date-arithmetic

I have two date fields in my Netezza table and I wish to find the number of days between them.

The original table I pull these two fields from has them recorded as DATE.

```
FIRST_DATE            SECOND_DATE
2020-04-20 00:00:00 2019-11-14 00:00:00
```

I wish to subtract SECOND_DATE from FIRST_DATE and wish to include the magnitude i.e. negative days in this example

There are -158 days between SECOND_DATE and FIRST_DATE

I have tried using the following but I only get the absolute number of days:

```
days_between(DATETIME(FIRST_FILL_DRUG_B),DATETIME(LAST_FILL_DRUG_A))
```

Is there a way to include the magnitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: 
`Select datediff(day, SECOND_DATE, FIRST_DATE) as magnitude from table1;`

Comment: I tried this but I think the version of Netezza I have is odd, there are functions that I've read about online that don't appear to work. I tried 'DATEDIFF('DAY',SECOND_DATE, FIRST_DATE)' but no joy. I tried DAY with double quotes, no quotes, DAYS but it is returning the following error: Function 'DATEDIFF(UNKNOWN, DATE, DATE)' does not exist
 Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
 You may need to add explicit typecasts

Comment: What kind of sql do you use?

Comment: IBM Netezza SQL

Comment: You can use CASE operator:  ```select case when DATETIME(FIRST_FILL_DRUG_B) > DATETIME(LAST_FILL_DRUG_A)  then  days_between(DATETIME(FIRST_FILL_DRUG_B),DATETIME(LAST_FILL_DRUG_A)) else -1* days_between(DATETIME(FIRST_FILL_DRUG_B),DATETIME(LAST_FILL_DRUG_A)) end as magnitude from table1```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extract(epoch from ...)` to do this. I was trying to do something similar where I also wanted to round the timestamps down to 0:00 to get the absolute number of days between two dates with timestamps throughout the day, so I am including that conversion as well.

The first method is using the exact timestamps and number of 24 hour periods between them. This is presuming that `end_date` and `start_date` are already datetime fields, but you could cast them to timestamp as below if they are not.

```
(extract(epoch from end_date) - 
    extract(epoch from start_date)
) / 86400
```

Or to calculate just the number of days between the two dates if you have timestamps throughout the day, cast to date, then cast back to datetime:

```
(extract(epoch from date(end_date)::timestamp) - 
    extract(epoch from date(start_date)::timestamp)
) / 86400
```